# Rails - Simple Form - Cocoon gem - Date picker works in edit but not in create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker, simple-form, nested-forms

I am using rails 5 with simple form and cocoon gem.

I have am model called Tenor.

The tenor form fields are nested inside parent models. The attributes in the tenor model are:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="form-inputs">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.input :express_interest, :as => :date_picker, :label => 'When are expressions of interest due?' %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.input :commencement, :as => :date_picker, :label => 'Commencement date' %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.input :expiry, :as => :date_picker, :label => 'Expiry date' %>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
          <%= link_to_remove_association 'Remove schedule', f %>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The tenor form fields are rendered inside another form, by this link:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :tenor do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
          <%= render 'tenors/tenor_fields', f: f %>

      <% end %>

      <%# unless @bip.tenor.present? %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add key dates', f, :tenor, partial: 'tenors/tenor_fields', force_non_association_create: true %>
      <%# end %>
```

There is a one to one association between bip and tenor.

The date_picker works fine when I edit an existing record. I can click on the calendar icon and it reveals the calendar.

However, when I try to create a new record, the date_picker doesn't do anything. I click the calendar icon and nothing happens. There are no console errors showing in the chrome inspector. I can type date in manually in the input box, but I can't select a date from the calendar. I can submit the form with manually inserted dates, but the date particulars do not save to the database (the records remain 'nil').

My inputs/date_picker_input.rb has

```
class DatePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input(wrapper_options)
    set_html_options
    set_value_html_option

    template.content_tag :div, class: 'input-group date datetimepicker' do
      input = super(wrapper_options) # leave StringInput do the real rendering
      input + input_button
    end
  end

  def input_html_classes
    super.push ''   # 'form-control'
  end

  private

  def input_button
    template.content_tag :span, class: 'input-group-btn' do
      template.content_tag :button, class: 'btn btn-default', type: 'button' do
        template.content_tag :span, '', class: 'fa fa-calendar'
      end
    end
  end

  def set_html_options
    input_html_options[:type] = 'text'
    input_html_options[:data] ||= {}
    input_html_options[:data].merge!(date_options: date_options)
  end

  def set_value_html_option
    return unless value.present?
    input_html_options[:value] ||= I18n.localize(value, format: display_pattern)
  end

  def value
    object.send(attribute_name) if object.respond_to? attribute_name
  end

  def display_pattern
    I18n.t('datepicker.dformat', default: '%d/%m/%Y')
  end

  def picker_pattern
    I18n.t('datepicker.pformat', default: 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  end

  def date_view_header_format
    I18n.t('dayViewHeaderFormat', default: 'MMMM YYYY')
  end

  def date_options_base
    {
        locale: I18n.locale.to_s,
        format: picker_pattern,
        dayViewHeaderFormat: date_view_header_format
    }
  end

  def date_options
    custom_options = input_html_options[:data][:date_options] || {}
    date_options_base.merge!(custom_options)
  end

end
```

Can anyone think of why the date_picker would work just fine if I am editing an existing record but will not work if I am trying to create a new record?

**Create actions in controllers**

Organisation

```
def create
    @organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @organisation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @organisation, notice: 'Organisation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @organisation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @organisation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Bip

```
def create
    @bip = Package::Bip.new(bip_params)
    # authorize @bip

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bip.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bip }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bip }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @bip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Tenor

```
def create
    @tenor = Tenor.new(tenor_params)
    # authorize @tenor

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tenor.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tenor }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tenor }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tenor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**New action**

Organisation

```
 def new
        @organisation = Organisation.new
        @organisation.bips
        # @organisation.bips.build_tenor
    end
```

Bips

```
def new
    @bip = Package::Bip.new
    # authorize @bip
  end
```

Tenor

```
def new
    @tenor = Tenor.new
    # authorize @tenor
  end
```

Comment: You didn't provide your controllers code, so I can only guess, but it seems that the problem is in the action "create" in your controller. I could try to tell more if you update your question with the code I've mentioned.

Comment: Which controller? I have them for Tenor, Organisation and Bip.

Comment: Well, I've made a mistake. I meant action "new" not "create".
I suspect that you do NOT have a valid tenor object when creating a new tenor, and because of that, your form is not working correctly.

Comment: I don't ask for a new tenor in the organisation new action. That's because it belongs to bip. So i don't know how best to ask for a new tenor (since the form fields for tenor are nested inside bips, which, in turn are nested inside organisation)

Comment: I don't remember exactly how to do this (last time I've been using Cocoon almost a year ago), but I think there is an action that is being called when you are adding a new cocoon field. There you should create a new Tenor object for your form.